# Table scrollbar disappearing on resize of window

Tags: css, scroll, resize, css-tables

I made a table for the back-office of an e-commerce site. The table content (tbody) has a fixed height and it is scrollable through a scrollbar on the right-hand side as depicted in this picture: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/6483/screenshot20110917at819.png

The problem is that if I resize the browser window, this table scrollbar diseappears: http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/4919/screenshot20110917at820.png

I know this is supposed to be normal behavior, but my customer insists to keep the table scrollbar even when resizing the window. Is there a way to implement this behavior?

Here is the css for reference: (the table body's class is scrollContent)

```
/* define height and width of scrollable area. Add 16px to width for scrollbar */
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%; 
}

/* set table header to a fixed position. WinIE 6.x only                                           */
/* In WinIE 6.x, any element with a position property set to relative and is a child of           */ 
/* an element that has an overflow property set, the relative value translates into fixed.    */
/* Ex: parent element DIV with a class of tableContainer has an overflow property set to     auto */
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

/* set THEAD element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers                */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

/* define the table content to be scrollable                                                  */
/* set TBODY element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
/* induced side effect is that child TDs no longer accept width: auto                     */
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: With CSS only, I don't think so. The best you could do is set a `min-width` on `body`, then the table's vertical scrollbar would be visible if you scrolled right using the window's horizontal scrollbar. Is JavaScript/jQuery an option?

Comment: can we see some html/a demo/more of the page?

Comment: JavaScript/JQuery is definitely an option, if it doesn't conflict with the existing scripts to sort the table contents. I must admit that I had to take the project on after two different developers who had a terrible way to organise code. But if a simple solution exists in javascript, I would definitely use it.

Comment: here is the source of the page:
http://jbourdon.org/source.txt

Comment: and the relevant CSS files:
http://presite.thesoulofthesamurai.net/css/fixedHeaders.css
http://presite.thesoulofthesamurai.net/css/productAdmin.css

Comment: think I remember a problem with a scrollbar somewhere ..wasnt "overflow: scroll;" a solution to show it always, though I think it didnt work for every browser

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The scrollbar does not actually "disappear", it just doesn't follow the right edge of the browser window when resizing. Adding a overflow:scroll is only relevant to the height of the element, ie. shoe the scrollbar even if the container is big enough for the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you if you change the overflow-x: scroll or auto should resolve the problem.  Since it's hidden they can't access the scroll bar which is probably their complaint.

The other option would be to run a javascript or jquery that would check for screen resolution and then replace the table with a different table or replace the images with smaller images. This would allow the table to resize down so that it could display in the non-maximized window.

/---- EDIT ----/

Check window resize (you also don't have to do this on the window you can do it on an element but the window will give you a more accurate read on whether they have resized their window.

```
var timerID = 0,
var winWidth = $(window).width(),
var winHeight = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        var winNewWidth = $(window).width(),
            winNewHeight = $(window).height();
        if(winWidth != winNewWidth || winHeight != winNewHeight)
        {
            window.clearTimeout(timerID);
            timerID = window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                // do something here
            },100)
        }
        winWidth = winNewWidth;
        winHeight = winNewHeight
    });
});
```

Comment: They actually want the horizontal scrollbar to be hidden. The problem is with the vertical scrollbar who doesn't not follow the right edge of the window when resized.

Comment: As far as the resolution check is concerned, the scrollbar should always be visible, even when resizing the window. I guess I could use the jQuery window.onresize then.

Comment: based on the criteria that your client is wanting the jquery window.resize would probably be the best concept.  See my edit

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem.

I haven't used the timeout part though. What is it used for?

Comment: I mean. I understand that you only want to update the value when the window size has actually changed but this case is very unlikely, isn;t it? I think that adding a timer will just use some processing resources for almost nothing. Anyway, thank you again for your answer!

Comment: Actually the timer is very important because in IE if you drag the window every pixel is a resize request and it can hang the browser.  In other words without that timeout you will crash the client browser on resize if they use IE.

Comment: I see. Where does this resizeWindow function come from? I get an unknown identifier error on Chrome and Safari.

Comment: sorry that was code that I used on another site.  that's where I parse whether or not it is page landing and then I do things based on page land vs. window resize.  That resizeWindow() can be replaced with //do code here

Answer (score 0):

Change the oversflow behavior from CSS to always display, like so:

```
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll; //this will make sure to always display the scrollbar, whether it's active (available for scrolling) or not.
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask my question correctly. As I said in the comments, The scrollbar does not actually "disappear", it just doesn't follow the right edge of the browser window when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

For reference to those who will visit this page later, here is the final code:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var winWidthDiff = 0;
var winHeightDiff = 0;
$i('scrollContent').style.maxWidth= ((winWidth-16)+"px");
$(window).resize(function(){
        var winNewWidth = $(window).width();
        var winNewHeight = $(window).height();
        winWidthDiff = winNewWidth - winWidth;
        winHeightDiff = winNewHeight - winHeight;
        winWidth = winNewWidth;
        winHeight = winNewHeight;
        scrollWidth = scrollWidth + winWidthDiff;
        scrollHeight = scrollHeight + winHeightDiff;
        $i('scrollContent').style.maxWidth= ((winWidth-16)+"px");
});
```